# Was ist der Unterschied zw. Person und Persönlichkeit?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Bsp: Ich bin eine kommunikative, kreative und belastbare Person/ Persönlichkeit

Answer (score 7):

Die Person meint die Person an sich *engl. person*.
Damit ist genauso die "rechtliche Person" als auch die Person mit der Persönlichkeit, ihrem Aussehen, ihrem Verhalten, ihren Gefühlen usw. gemeint. Kann Synonym zu *Mensch* verwendet werden, meint aber nicht die Gattung Mensch, sondern den Menschen als Teil der Gesellschaft.

Persönlichkeit meint die Persönlichkeit *engl. personality* als Attribut der Person.

Eine Person hat eine ihr zugeordnete Persönlichkeit, aber eine Persönlichkeit ist nicht zwingend einer Person zuzuordnen. So können viele Menschen aufbrausend oder schüchtern sein, aber das heißt nicht, dass aufbrausend bzw. schüchtern auf die Person schließen lässt.

Comment: Stimme weitgehend zu, nur würde ich Persönlichkeit als **Menge** von (kognitiven,emotionalen) Attributen beschreiben, in denen sich Menschen unterscheiden können. Bsp.: $\{$schüchtern, wissbegierig,$\dots\}$ vs. $\{$nicht schüchtern, wissbegierig,$\dots\}$

Comment: +1 Ich stimme auch zu. Ergänzung: manchmal werden öffentliche Personen wie "Promis", Großunternehmer, Politiker o.ä. auch als "Persönlichkeit" bezeichnet, z.B.: "`Er war eine herausragende Persönlichkeit.`". Hier verwendet man "Persönlichkeit" hervorhebend/abgrenzend.

Answer (score 4):

Der Satz: „Ich **bin** eine kommunikative, kreative und belastbare **Person**.“ ist völlig in Ordnung.

Der Satz: „Ich **habe** eine kommunikative, kreative und belastbare **Persönlichkeit**.“ ist auch völlig in Ordnung.

Die Persönlichkeit ist eine Menge von Eigenschaften einer Person.

Außerdem hat das Wort Persönlichkeit aber noch eine weitere Bedeutung, nämlich „eine wichtige oder berühmte“ Person.

Der Satz: „Ich **bin** eine kommunikative, kreative und belastbare **Persönlichkeit**.“ ist also nur dann in Ordnung, wenn man selbst eine wichtige oder berühmte Person ist oder sich zumindest dafür hält.

Comment: Eine echte Persönlichkeit würde sich meiner Meinung nach nie *selbst* als "Persönlichkeit" bezeichnen, aus reiner Bescheidenheit.

Answer (score 1):

Eine kreative Persönlichkeit wäre eine Person, bei der die Kreativität eine herrausragende Charaktereigenschaft ist.

Eine kreative Person kann dagegen einfach eine Person sein, die man eher als kreativ als als nicht kreativ bezeichnen würde.

Answer (score 0):

"Er ist eine Person" wäre banale Aussage, da jeder Mensch eine Person ist. " Er ist eine Persönlichkeit" heißt er hat positive Eigenschaften, die ihn aus der Masse hervorheben.